# Searching the text in a column using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am having a table say with the column names `No_of_pole` and `Pol_st_typ` with datatypes integer and character respectively. I want to check if `No_of_pole` is 2 then `Pol_st_type` starts with the keyword 'double' and if `No_of_pole` is 3 then `Pol_st_type` starts with the keyword 'tripole'. How to accomplish this using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Do you need both condition or one of two is enough?

Comment: Need both condition.

Comment: Can u show us some queries u already tried please ?

Comment: SELECT "No_of_pole","Pol_st_typ" 
IF No_of_pole = '2' THEN Pol_st_typ = 'Double pole - Section + Through'
ELSE No_of_pole = '3' THEN Pol_st_typ = 'Tri Pole - Through'
END IF;
FROM network."Pole_Structure"

Comment: CASE
    WHEN no_of_pole = 2 THEN
      pol_st_typ = double_pole
   END CASE;

Comment: Please show us some sample data and the expected output based on that. Edit your question don't post it as a comment.

Comment: I wasn't able to attach the image due to reputation.

Comment: Do not add sample data as an image, add it as (formatted) **text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT "No_of_pole","Pol_st_typ" 
FROM network."Pole_Structure" 
WHERE (No_of_pole = '2' AND Pol_st_typ LIKE 'Double%') 
       OR (No_of_pole = '3' AND Pol_st_typ LIKE 'Tri Pole%')
```

Comment: @AhamedFarook : if the above anwer gave the solution, you should accept it to denote you no longer need help with this question.

Comment: Sorry I am new to postgreSQL.

Comment: @AhamedFarook If this answer worked then click on `tick` symbol